# How do I change my app from Draft Internal Testing to Internal Testing in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

My app is stuck in Draft Internal Testing for some reason. I have completed all the steps Play Console wanted me to do, including submitting rating info, store listing, etc.

I fiddled around the console and decided to move from Internal Testing to Closed Alpha testing hoping the draft stage would go away but sadly it didn't and now it is under review. I was under the impression that the app wouldn't need to be review if it was released under internal testing.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem... Do you fix it?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Is your app in Draft still?

Comment: I have the same problem, take 2 hours still not fix

Comment: I have the same issue, and no info available in Google Play Console docs regarding this, except that you maybe have to wait 48 hour after initially uploading your app, during which time the app has a temp name and store listing info.

Comment: I have this issue. I believe Google is reviewing my release nice and slowly, as under "Publishing Overview" I have a bunch of items under "changes in Review", clicking the little question mark tool tip says "These changes are being reviewed. Changes must be approved by Google before you can publish them.". So it is a waiting game and apparently takes days.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Releases Overview" on left pane:

[image: releases overview]

Find the release row with "Draft" status and click the blue arrow on the right corner:
[image: releases list]

Follow the steps provided by UI and pay attention to warnings. For me, I had to setup "Financial Features" then go through this flow again and finish by hitting "Save and publish"
[image: publish with warnings]

Answer (score 1):

You should click blue arrow on your photo and choose "view versions" that top right and there you can make your app that everyone see

Comment: Add screenshot(s) for clarity

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was that in the middle of the internal publication I got a warning that I had a pending declaration regarding "Government apps". I clicked on the warning, filled out the declaration and finished the creation of the internal release. But by navigating away in the middle of the internal release creation my internal release was stuck in draft state. And the solution was that I picked up respective edited again the internal release that was in draft state, went again through all the steps (most of them already filled out) and clicked on publish and this time the internal release was published.

Comment: "I picked up respective edited again". Huh?

Comment: I think I clicked on the internal publication in draft state and published it again i.e. went again through all the steps (short description, etc.) to publish it.